# How to declare an array in java

Tags: java

What does the below line of code mean?
is it a legal way to declare or define an array.
I googled it but couldn't find any information regarding this.

int[] []x[]

Answer (score -1):

This is a valid line of code. It references a 3 dimensional integer array. Following codes are equivalent:

`int[][][]x`

`int[][]x[]`

`int[]x[][]`

`int x[][][]`

All of them are reference to a 3 dimensional integer array. You can declare a 10x10x10 size array like the following:

`x = new int[10][10][10];`